# Laravel 5 join table

Tags: sql, laravel

Is any possible to join table users only on column where my user id != user id from db.

```
$games = Games::where('status', '=', 2)->where('owner_user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orWhere('join_user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('games.updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

[image]

Question is:
How join user table, where owner_user_id and join_user_id != 30.
So I only want join user table for 1304 and 49. Its only example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Games::where('status', '=', 2)
      ->join('users', function($join){
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'games.owner_user_id')
                 ->where('user.id', '!=', Auth::user()->id);
            })
      ->orderBy('games.updated_at', 'desc')
      ->paginate(10);
```

Something like this?

Comment: I have changed first query.I don't know which column return my id, but  I want to join user table not for my id, but for other id which is not my. One from this two column return `games.owner_user_id` or `games.join_user_id`. Two ids, one is my, other is not my and i don't know which. I only know that I want to join user table only for NOT my id.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `use` function to pass data to `join`:

```
      $id = 1; // whatever id of other user
      Games::where('status', '=', 2)
          ->join('users', function($join)use($id){ // Here you need to pass user Id
                $join->on('users.id', '=', 'games.owner_user_id')
                     ->where('user.id', '!=', $id);
                })
          ->orderBy('games.updated_at', 'desc')
          ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Check my 1 comment. Please